# Why am I getting "Cannot use a leading .. to exit above the top directory" error?

Tags: asp.net, forms

I am a beginner in ASP.NET and I try to write a simple web form application. In this login form, I check both username and password and if they are correct, it redirects on another page with this code:

```
Response.Redirect("../forms/provinces_Status.aspx");
```

In my Visual Studio, it runs without problems, the application works correctly. But when published and run in the IIS, I get this error:

```
Cannot use a leading .. to exit above the top directory
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Try this `Response.Redirect("~/forms/provinces_Status.aspx");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always specify your URLs with a leading `~`, where the `~` character represents the root of your application, e.g:

```
Response.Redirect("~/forms/provinces_Status.aspx");
```

The different behavior you're experiencing is likely due to the fact how the app is hosted in IIS, e.g. in a virtual directory locally (`http://localhost/myapp/default.aspx`) and in the web site root when published (`http://server/default.aspx`).